# Can I attach several commands to the same jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

in simple words:

Is this:

```
$('#password').html('Weak').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'color' : '#FFFFFF'});
```

equals to this?

```
$('#password').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'color' : '#FFFFFF'});
$('#password').html('Weak')
```

They work the same for me - but I just wanted to be sure that they are truly the same...

Answer (score 6):

Almost.

```
$('#password').html('Weak').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'color' : '#FFFFFF'});
```

Builds a `jQuery` object for the selector `#password` once.

```
$('#password').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'color' : '#FFFFFF'});
$('#password').html('Weak')
```

Builds a `jQuery` object for the selector `#password` twice.

Does it matter much this time? **Not really**: `#something` is [heavily optimized](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L144) in jQuery to quickly use `document.getElementById` to match the correct element.

However, if you have

```
$('input[value^=your_complex_selector],div div div,img[src$=.jpg]')
```

and you keep calling it again and again without caching it... you can see where we are going.

You can get the performance advantage of chaining, without the loss of readability, by assigning the jQuery object to a variable:

```
var password = $('#password');
password.css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'color' : '#FFFFFF'});
password.html('Weak');
```

Comment: in the last example you meant: obj.css... & obj.html... right?

Comment: @Alon: Certainly did, thanks :P (although I was lazy and renamed `obj` to `password`, rather than change two variables to `obj` :P)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is always better to chain the jquery commands. That will save jquery to fetch the element everytime.

```
$('#password').html('Weak').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'color' : '#FFFFFF'});
```

is better than even though they do the same function.

```
$('#password').css({'background-color' : '#FF0000' , 'color' : '#FFFFFF'});
$('#password').html('Weak')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's *usually* the same thing, but some methods affect the set of selected elements, so it's not *necessarily* the same. In your particular case, yes, it's exactly the same.

It's more efficient to use a "chain" because the DOM only has to be searched once. When the lookup is by "id" as in your example, that's not a huge savings, but it's something.

Answer (score 0):

answer is **almost yes**, they are equal, but first query will work faster.

Second query search the document twice for the #password element

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called chaining and is preferred to doing the second example because in the second example you are having the find the DOM element again instead of using the one already in use in the first example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the result is the same, but with your first approach you only have to find that element once, and jQuery will create only one jQuery object, thus saving memory.

It's called *chaining*. One of the great feature of libraries such as jQuery.

You can optimize your calls by assigning a jQuery object to a variable, so you don't have to call the jquery function multiple times, saving memory and speed.

```
var $password = $('#password');

$password.css({

  'background-color': '#FF0000',
  'color': '#FFFFFF'

});

$password.html('Weak');
```